# Closing and releasing the file after use

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, server.mappath

```
 try
 {
      using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
      {
                path = Server.MapPath(@"\\Files\\" + "file.txt");
                StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255"));
                tw.Write("Hello dear file");
               
                tw.Flush();
                tw.Close();
                tw.Dispose();

                stream.Close();
                stream.Dispose();  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception  ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;// Error
            return null;
        }
        return path;
```

**When used again the error is:**

> The process cannot accsess the file because another process is using the file

How to release the use of the file to enable reuse?

Comment: To confirm if it is releasing the lock, manually rename the file, you will get an error if the file is still locked

Comment: You should be using a `using` statement for the `StreamWriter`, just as you are for the `MemoryStream`. You should be doing that for ALL disposable objects used in a limited scope.

Comment: Then I can only conclude that you're opening that file somewhere else as well. Unless your system is corrupt, exiting the using block is guaranteed to close the file so if it's open, it's not that code doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this pattern everywhere you are working with the file:

```
    using (_httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
//code to do
}
```